# How to access calling folder when Ruby script is run as executable?

Tags: ruby

I have a .rb script that access and edit all .txt files in same directory with `Dir.glob('*.txt') do |rb_file|`

If I call it from terminal `ruby myscript.rb` all works fine.

Then I made an executable, launched with double click on Mac OS, as explained at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108143/calling-a-ruby-script-by-double-clicking-does-not-work) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721369/how-to-execute-a-ruby-script-in-terminal) answers. I started file with `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`, gave permissions `chmod +x myscript.rb`, and opened it with terminal.

Ruby is working but when I try to access files in the same directory, the script can't find them. In fact, the script look for these files in /Users/myname directory.

How can I access the original directory where the double clicked file is?

I tried with `./` without success.
Absolute path is not an option, unless programmatically retrieved.

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you should be able to use this to get the directory the ruby script is in regardless of how you invoke it.

```
File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
```

If I make a simple script that simply `puts` the above and place it in `~/tmp/foo.rb` this is the output. My prompt is my current directory followed by a '$'. In every case the same value is returned.

```
~/tmp $ ruby foo.rb
/Users/philip/tmp
~ $ ruby tmp/foo.rb
/Users/philip/tmp
~ $ ruby /Users/philip/tmp/foo.rb
/Users/philip/tmp
~ $ cd /
/ $ ruby /Users/philip/tmp/foo.rb
/Users/philip/tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method [`Kernel#__dir__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__) which returns the directory of the file the call to `__dir__` is in. (It is basically equivalent to [`File.dirname`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-dirname)`(`[`File.realpath`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-realpath)`(`[`__FILE__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/keywords_rdoc.html)`))`.)